# Measure of the Translation of a Single Set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

> Let $E \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ be a bounded measurable. Suppose there exists a bounded, countably infinite set $I \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ for which $\{x + E \}_{x \in I}$ is a pairwise disjoint collection.  Then $m(E)=0$.

First, since both $E$ and $I$ are bounded, there exist positive numbers $M$ and $N$ such that $|y| \le M$ and $|x| \le N$ for every $y \in E$ and $x \in I$, and therefore $|y+x| \le |y| + |x| \le M + N$, which shows that $\bigcup_{x \in I} (x + E)$ is bounded. This means that its contained in a closed, bounded interval whose finite length is an upper bound on $m(\bigcup_{x \in I} (x + E))$. Since the collection of translates of $E$ is countable and disjoint, we can use the additive property of $m$ to arrive at

$$m(\bigcup_{x \in I} (x + E)) = \sum_{x \in I} m(x+E) = \sum_{x\in I} m(E)$$

Unless $m(E)=0$, the RHS side will be infinite, while the LHS is finite. Hence, $m(E) =0$ in order to avoid contradiction.

How does this sound?

Comment: Who says $I$ is bounded?

Comment: @DjuraMarinkov Sorry. I forgot to include that.

Comment: Sounds alright if no one says opposite ;)